# MFMessageComposeViewController use for charity donation through SMS

Tags: ios, sms, donations

I faced App Store rejection recently based on the following review guideline- "The collection of donations must be done via a web site in `Safari` or an `SMS`".

I was opening the PayPal link in a web browser control instead of the native `Safari` app which I have corrected now. But my app also has an option to donate through `SMS` where I have used `MFMessageComposeViewController.`

Will it be approved by App Store as I am using `MFMessageComposeViewController` instead of redirecting user to the native `SMS` app?

As per my understanding `MFMessageComposeViewController` is also a safe way and can not be modified once presented. Please let me know what do you think about this problem and share you experiences. I dont want to face the rejection again.